# Multithreading in order with iterations

Tags: python, multithreading

Is it possible, in a Pythonical way, to do multithreading with iteration of a for loop, where rows of data is appended to a dataframe in a ordered manner? Let's, as an example, imagine that I have a for loop iterating 1000 times, where each iteration appends data as a row to a dataframe.

The order in which the row is appended to the dataframe is crucial. Therefore, it is important that the order in which the dataframe is appended, is aligned to the iterations of the for loop.

The following image attached is an example of what i would like:

[image: Example]

**For Loop:**

```
username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"
sql = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM {table}', con=engine)
for i, j, v, k in sql.itertuples(index=False):
    df = rest(username, password).get_number(number=i, name=j)
```

Example of results of synchronous iteration:

```
Iteration 0: number = 14, name = "Hansen"
Iteration 1: number = 2 , name = "Jens"
Iteration 2: number = 58, name = "Michael"
Iteration 3: number = 44, name = "Mendy"
Iteration 4: number = 23, name = "Treo"
Iteration 5: number = 15, name = "Emma"
```

Because of multithreading iterations of for loop, we don't control the order:

```
Iteration 2: number = 58, name = "Michael"
Iteration 5: number = 15, name = "Emma"
Iteration 3: number = 44, name = "Mendy"
Iteration 0: number = 14, name = "Hansen"
Iteration 1: number = 2 , name = "Jens"
Iteration 4: number = 23, name = "Treo"
```

**Add row to Dataframe:**

```
# creating an empty Dictionary
dict = {}

class rest:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.url = 'xxx:'

def get_number(self, number, name):

    r = requests.get(f'{self.url}{number}', auth=(self.username, self.password))

    dict["number"] = number
    dict["name"] = r.json()['name']

    df.loc[len(df)] = [dict["number"], dict["name"]] # ADD ROW TO DATAFRAME
```

When appending a row of number and name, we should then order so that the threads append to the dataframe in the correct order:

```
Iteration 0: dict={"number":"14", "name":"Hansen"}
Iteration 1: dict={"number":"2", "name":"Jens"}
Iteration 2: dict={"number":"58", "name":"Michael"}
Iteration 3: dict={"number":"44", "name":"Mendy"}
Iteration 4: dict={"number":"23", "name":"Treo"}
Iteration 5: dict={"number":"15", "name":"Emma"}
```

**Dataframe:**

```
     number     name   
0    14         Hansen
1    2          Jens
2    58         Michael
3    44         Mendy
4    23         Treo
5    15         Emma
...
```

**CODE UPDATE / EDIT**

Main file:

```
from secondFile import *
from sqlalchemy import *
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sql = pd.read_sql_query('select * from {table}', con=engine)
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['number', 'name'])

    with Pool(5) as p:
        result = p.map(rest(username, password).get_number, sql.itertuples())
        print(result) # Prints one single row multiple times and no other rows

    for r in result:
        df.loc[len(df)] = r
```

second file (secondFile):

```
# creating an empty Dictionary
dict = {}

class rest:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.url = 'xxx:'

def get_number(self, *args):

    r = requests.get(f'{self.url}{args[0][1]}', auth=(self.username, self.password))

    dict["name"] = r.json()["name"]
    dict["number"] = args[0][1]


    print(dict) # Prints all rows individually as a dict
    return dict
```

Comment: Could you afford the time and space to collect the data in a `dict` indexed by iteration number? You could later iterate over the `dict` in the order of iteration.

Comment: Should be doable. Although, i imagine that there will be 100.000's of iterations in the future. Do you mind elaborating your solution? It sounds interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way for this to work is to make a pool of processes which go and fetch data and use `map` to order the return values:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def f(*args):
    r = requests.get(...)
    return {"name": r.json()['name'], ...}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with ThreadPool(5) as p:
        result = p.map(f, sql.itertuples())

    for r in result:
        # add each r to a dataframe
```

*Update:* Changed over to a `multithreaded` pool which should work well with blocking calls in `requests`.

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately i couldn't make it work. I have updated my question with a "Code update / edit" section, where you can see my attempt. I hope you have time to help me further. Also, thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok, your: `dict = {}` is part of the problem. See my solution where I have: `return {...}` This creates a `new` dict for every `return`.

Comment: Unfortunately, i receive this error: "_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'pandas.core.frame.Pandas'>: attribute lookup Pandas on pandas.core.frame failed". From what i read i believe that it is due to sql.itertuples()

Comment: Ok, sorry, you need a `multithreading` answer. I'll see if I can revise this.

Comment: Alright! Now threading works, but for some reason only one row is showing when printing results. When printing results inside threadpool loop: "with Threadpool(5) as p: result = p.map(VirkRest(username, password).virk_get_customers, econ.itertuples()) print(result)" , then it just prints {"number":23, "name":"Treo"} multiple times. When print(result) is outside of loop, then it prints [{"number":23, "name":"Treo"}, {"number":23, "name":"Treo"}, ... {"number":23, "name":"Treo"}], instead of all the rows. When printing dict right before return , then it prints all rows

Comment: What! You're still using `dict`?

Comment: I have updated the code in section "Code update / edit". I find this particular issue very weird, as i can print(dict) before return dict and it prints all rows, but when i print(result) it just prints the same row

Comment: When I say 'Why are you still using dict?' I mean, don't use dict.  Make a new dict every time!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a nicer way would be is to use [`queue.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) provided in standard library. They have explained in the docs how to maintain the priority or order of the queue using dataclasses in the docs.

The theory is to develop producer and consumer implementation, where all of the threads will put your data into this queue and one separate thread will consume this queue and insert row in same order as you wish. You can rely on priority queue to produce your row or data in ordered manner as you would expect.

Also, you will have to inherit the existing PriorityQueue with custom stuffs and possibly override the default `PriorityQueue.get` method to make it return only processed rows or data. And also a wrapper around your data indicating if it has been processed or not.